# Firefox OS: start searching on enter key press

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, firefox-os, search-form

I am new in Firefox OS. I have a search box.

After pressing the submit button it shows results perfectly. But I want to add keyboardevent like press enter button it will show result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
      $("#SearchText").keydown(function (e) {
          var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

          if (keyCode == 13) {
            //stop CR & do submit here instead
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
            return false;
          }
        });
```

It intercepts every key press in the search text field and checks for Return.